# Ho to store results of loop in .csv ? (Python)

Tags: python, csv

I'm running tweepy and I don't know how to store tweets in a csv file

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=search+
    lang="en").items(num_tweets):

    data = tweet.text
    print (tweet.text)

import csv
c = csv.writer(open("file.csv", "w"))
c.writerow(data)
```

csv.Error: iterable expected, not float

I'l also tried float(data) but it's not working.

My goal is to store these tweets in csv file to have the format required by cool.api

```
# batch example
cool.api([
    "I love Stack Overflow!",
    "Barack Obama is better at Twitter than Donald Trump."
])
```

Comment: `.writerow` expects *an iterable*, and the error message indicates that you are passing it a `float`. `float(data)` won't help that!

Comment: Check out the data type of `data`. See if you can figure out why it isn't an iterator and how to cast it as one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix. The argument passed to writer must be an iterable (list, tuple, etc.) so that it can write each thing in the utterable to the cvs file. So all you need to do is put data in a list:

```
c.writerow([data])
```

You probably want to make a list and add tweets to it as you go through your for loop, or write a new row each time.

```
import csv
f = open("file.csv", "w")
c = csv.writer(f)
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=search+
    lang="en").items(num_tweets):
    c.writerow([tweet.txt])
f.close()
```

Comment: I tried different methods but only one tweet is stored, with pandas I have all tweets in one row but still struggling with delimiters. Thanks!

Comment: It worked even in append mode! Thanks! All I need is [] delimiters.